# Como percorrer a string por palavras ou por letras?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Código:**

```
while True:
    regras, numero_frases = map(int, input().split())
    if regras == 0 and numero_frases == 0:
        break
    dici = {}
    for r in range(regras):
        subs = input().replace(' ', '').split('->')
        dici[subs[0]] = subs[1]
        if subs[0] == 0 and subs[1] == 0:
            break
    for f in range(numero_frases):
        frase = input().split()
        for p in frase:
            if p in dici:
                frase[frase.index(p)] = dici[p]
        print(*frase)
```

**Entrada:**

```
2 3 (número de regras e frases)
Rat -> Rato (substituições)
Rome -> Roma
O Rat roeu ( A saída deve ser a frase baseada na troca da regra)
a roupa do rei
de Rome
1 1
e -> i
e o vento levou
0 0
```

**saída:**

```
O Rato roeu
a roupa do rei
de Roma
i o vinto livou
```

O código corrige palavras ou letras isoladas, mas quero que também funcione com letras nas palavras, grato!

Comment: Sei que as palavras ficam organizadas em [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) e caso alguma palavra duma frase não possa ser encontrada no trie é utilizada a [distância Levenshtein](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_Levenshtein) para determinar as candidatas a substituição dentro do trie. Agora dessa forma que está fazendo é contra producente pois além de informar as palavras corretas você em tese teria que informar todas os possibilidade de erros de grafia para cada palavra inserida. Inserir duas regras de substituição é simples o duro é criar um dicionário de 1000 palavras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu não entendi exatamente qual é a sua duvida, mas acredito que se for só para percorrer a string por palavras, você pode usar o método "`split()`" para que a string vire uma lista de palavras. Por exemplo:

```
nossaString = "Olá, Marcio! Tudo bem, amigo?"

for j in nossaString.split():
    print(j)
```

**Saída:**

```
Olá,
Marcio!
Tudo
bem,
amigo?
```

Se for letra por letra, você pode usar o método "`list()`", por exemplo:

```
nossaString = "Eu gosto de sorvete"

for i in list(nossaString):
    print(i)
```

**Saída:**

```
E
u

g
o
s
t
o

d
e

s
o
r
v
e
t
e
```